# GrantPermissionRule leads to PermissionException

Tags: android, testing-support-library

I've tried today the new android testing support lib. I need the write external storage permission for my tests so I've created the following test with the new GrantPermissionRule.

ExternalDirTest.java

```
    @Rule
    public GrantPermissionRule mRuntimePermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
        Application.getApplication().createDir();
    }
```

Application.java

```
    public void createDir() throws IOException {
        new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test").createNewFile();
    }
```

Officially I get the permission (visible in the app settings). Nevertheless I get the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:280)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:948)
at test.app.directory.Application.createDir(EarApplication.java:253)
at test.app.directory.ExternalDirTest.test(ExternalDirTest.java:24)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule$RequestPermissionStatement.evaluate(GrantPermissionRule.java:109)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:58)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:369)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1932)
```

If I test the code manual it works perfectly.

Has someone facing the same problem or is it maybe a bug in the library itself?

Comment: Try to add `Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` also. also check you are not forgetting the permissions in andorid_manifest

Comment: both are already added

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: nope currently not. I've filed a bug, see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64389280

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should now be fixed in version 1.0.2-alpha2

See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64389280

Comment: Not for everyone apparently and certainly not for me.